# What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

What is the sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$ and does it matter, for finite n, if $|p|>1$ or $|p|<1$ ?

Edition :

Why can I integrate take sum and then take the derivative ? I think that kind of trick is not always allowed.

ps. I've tried this approach but I made mistake when taking derivative, so I've asked, mayby I should use some program (or on-line app) for symbolic computation.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: Try to integrate your sum.

Comment: Multiply by $p$ and subtract.

Comment: These questions are not exactly the same as your question, but some answers gives a more general answers there, so you can find answer to your question there (or you can try to use a similar method and a make the generalization yourself).
[1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proof-by-induction-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1)
[2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-r-1d-r-cdot-2r)
[3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/what-is-the-limit-of-sum-limits-n-1-inftyn2-3n)

Comment: If you think your methods are "not allowed" ... use them anyway to get a formula, then prove the formula by induction.

Comment: For your question about why integrating, summing, and taking the derivative is allowed, remember that for fixed $n$ this is just a polynomial in $p$, so your sum is about as nicely behaved as possible. In particular, all of the operations you've suggested are perfectly kosher.

Comment: See also: [Formula for calculating $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119636).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kp^k=\frac{p(np^{n+1}-(n+1)p^n+1)}{(p-1)^2}\tag{*}$$

Proof by induction:

1. $n=1$: $ p=\frac{p(p^{1+1}-(1+1)p^1+1)}{(p-1)^2}=\frac{p(p^{2}-2p+1)}{(p-1)^2}=p$

---

2. $$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   (n+1)p^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n kp^k&=&(n+1)p^{n+1} + \frac{p(np^{n+1}-(n+1)p^n+1)}{(p-1)^2}\\
   &=&\frac{(n+1)p^{n+1}(p^2-2p+1)}{(p-1)^2} + \frac{p(np^{n+1}-(n+1)p^n+1)}{(p-1)^2}\\
   &=&\frac{np^{n+3}+p^{n+3}-np^{n+2}-2p^{n+2}+p}{(p-1)^2}\\
   &=&\frac{p((n+1)p^{n+2}-(n+1+1)p^{n+1}+1)}{(p-1)^2}\\
   &=&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} kp^k
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$

If $p=1$, we expect $\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot 1^k= \frac12 n(n+1)$:
Since the RHS of $(*)$ gives $\frac00$, when we insert $p=1$,  we apply L'Hospital's rule two times:
$$
\lim_{p\to 1} \frac{p(np^{n+1}-(n+1)p^n+1)}{(p-1)^2}
=\lim_{p\to 1} \frac{n(n+2)p^{n+1}-(n+1)^2p^{n}+1}{2(p-1)}\\
=\frac12 \lim_{p\to 1} (n(n+1)(n+2)p^{n}-n(n+1)^2p^{n-1})\\
=\frac12 n(n+1) \underbrace{\lim_{p\to 1} p^{n-1}((n+2)p-(n+1))}_{=1}\\
$$
If $n\to \infty$, the series converges due to ratio test ($\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{(k+1)}{k}p\right|<1$), when $|p|<1$. You'll get
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kp^k = \frac p{(p-1)^2}+\underbrace{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{np^{n+2}-(n+1)p^{n+1}}{(p-1)^2}}_{=0}
= \frac p {(p-1)^2}
$$

Answer (score 17):

Start with $f(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n p^i=\frac {p(p^n-1)}{p-1}$

your answer is $\ pf'(p)$ (compute it both ways...)

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another way:
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n ip^i &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n p^j \\ &=
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p^{n+1}-p^i}{p-1} \\ &=
n\frac{p^{n+1}}{p-1} - \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{i=1}^n p^i \\ &=
n\frac{p^{n+1}}{p-1} - \frac{p^{n+1}-1}{(p-1)^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I like calculus. My first line would be

$ Q(p) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}p^i  = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i+1)p^i  =  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{d}{dp} p^{i+1} = \frac{d}{dp} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  p^{i+1} $

(Writing $Q(p)$ for your function $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$)

That was the old swap the sum and the differentiation trick. It remains to the sum the geometric series and differentiate it.

---

Since we used calculus, we can use the same method will also work for the continuous problem $  R(p) = \int\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i $