# Find the general formula for the partial sum? $\sum 2^{(n-1)} \cdot n$ from $n=1$ to $k$

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the general formula for the following partial sum

$$ \sum_{n=1}^k 2^{n-1} \cdot n $$

Comment: See also [How to compute the  formula $\sum  \limits_{r=1}^d r \cdot 2^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11464), [Mathematical Induction (summation): $\sum^n_{k=1} k2^k =(n-1)(2^{n+1})+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/650527) and [How do we get the result of the summation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k \cdot 2^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120091)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this just $(\frac{d}{dx}\{1 +x+x^2+\cdots + x^k\})|_{x=2}$ ? The series sums to $(1-x^{k+1})/(1-x)$, so its derivative is $\frac{-(k+1)x^k(1-x)+(1-x^{k+1})}{(1-x)^2}$, which, evaluated at $x=2$,  simplifies to $(k+1)2^k+1-2^{k+1}=(k+1-2)2^k +1=\boxed{(k-1)2^k+1}$.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the simplest and most natural way to compute the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Setting
$$
S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k2^{n-1}n,
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
S_k&=&\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^{n-1}n=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}2^n(n+1)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}2^nn+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}2^n=2\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}2^{n-1}n+\frac{1-2^k}{1-2}\\
&=&2^k-1+2\sum_{n=1}^k2^{n-1}n-2\cdot2^{k-1}k=(1-k)2^k-1+2S_k,
\end{eqnarray}
it follows that
$$
S_k=(k-1)2^k+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2^n$.  By using this formula for different values of $k$  we can derive a formula for the sum without the $n$ factor:

\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{k} &=& 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-1}\\
&=& 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + 2^{k-2}\\
&=& 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2}+2^{k-3}+2^{k-3} \\
&=& \cdots\\
&=& (2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+\cdots+1) + 1\\
&=& 1+\sum_{n=1}^k 2^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^k 2^{n-1} = 2^{n}-1$.
Now we can introduce the factor of $n$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^k n2^{n-1} &=& 1 + 2*2^1 + 3*2^2 + 4*2^3 + \cdots +n 2^{n-1}\\
&=& 1 \\
&& +2^1 + 2^1 \\
&& +2^2+2^2+2^2\\
&& + \vdots \\
&& +2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}+\cdots + 2^{k-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sum each of the columns of the last line.  The first column is 
$1+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{k-1}=2^k-1$, the second column is $2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{k-1}=2^k-2$
and the $i$'th column is $2^i+2^{i+1}+\cdots+2^{k-1}=2^k-2^i$.  Therefore the whole sum can also be written
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^k n2^{n-1} &=& (2^k-1)+(2^k-2^1)+(2^k-2^2)+\cdots + (2^k-2^{k-1})\\
&=& k 2^k - \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^{n-1}\\
&=& k2^k-(2^k-1)\\
&=& 1+(k-1)2^k\\
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the most elementary derivation I can think of.  There are faster and simpler methods as well.  Hopefully this was helpful to you.