# A closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot2^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot(2^i)$
How to write $f(n)$ only in terms of $n$.

I am unable to find. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematical Induction (summation): $\sum^n_{k=1} k2^k =(n-1)(2^{n+1})+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650527/mathematical-induction-summation-sumn-k-1-k2k-n-12n12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that
$$
\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^i.
$$
Hence
$$
x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix^i
$$
You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

> An elementary approach based upon the *[geometric series summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^ni2^i}&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^i1\right)2^i=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i2^i\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j\leq i\leq n}2^i\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j}^n2^i=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}2^{i+j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n2^j\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}2^{i}=\sum_{j=1}^n2^j\cdot\frac{2^{n-j+1}-1}{2-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n2^{n+1}-\sum_{j=1}^n2^j\tag{4}\\
> &=n2^{n+1}-\left(\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}-1\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2^{n+1}(n-1)+2}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we represent the factor $i$ as sum.
- In (2) we exchange  the order of summation and shift  the  inner index   $i$ to start  from $i=0$.
- In (3) we apply the *geometric series summation formula* to the inner sum.
- In (4) we simplify  and split  the sum.
- In (5) we calculate both sums by again applying the *geometric series summation formula* to  the right-hand sum.
- In (6) we do some final simplifications.