# breaking a summation when the index is a factor

Tags: summation

I am  evaluating the sum
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ip^i$.

in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180266/516412)
the following identity is used :

$$\sum_{i=1}^n ip^i = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n p^j$$

I don't see where this comes from, maybe one could help me out ?

As a computer science student, it looks as if we were doing two loops, but I dont get it

Thanks for the help

Comment: Essentially, the following pyramid can be summed by rows then columns or vice versa, $$\begin{array}{}p^1\\p^2+p^2\\p^3+p^3+p^3\\\dots\\p^n+p^n+p^n\dots+p^n\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n ip^i =\sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{(p^i+\dots+p^i)}_{\text{repeated $i$ times}} =\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i p^i=\sum_{1\leq j\leq i\leq n} p^i=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=j}^n p^i.$$
where at the last step we interchange the sums. The last sum is the same
of $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n p^j$, just rename the indices.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes more sense, but how do you go from $j=1$ to $i$ to $i=j$ to $n$ in the last step ?

Comment: @anastygnome I added one more step

Comment: Oh dear, I had forgotten about that !
Thanks!