# What is the closed form for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\theta^n, 0 \lt \theta \lt 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I have the following series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\theta^n, 0 \lt \theta \lt 1$$

I've seen lots of resources saying this is convergent. And using convergence tests to prove that.

**Question**:

> But is there any formula which gives the summation in closed form?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n = x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = x\frac d {dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \ldots$.

Comment: @amsmath thank you! that finally results in $\theta/((1-\theta)^2)$. Hope this is the right answer?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112394/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-nxn-1

Comment: This is a copy modify of this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112394/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-nxn-1

Answer (score 0):

I guess the last two equations of this answer, (6) and (7), pack the real punch.  The rest is just . . .  commentary.

Working off the comment of amsmath, for $0 < \theta < 1$ we have

$\sum_1^\infty n \theta^n = \theta \sum_1^\infty n\theta^{n - 1} = \theta \dfrac{d}{d\theta}\sum_1^\infty \theta^n, \tag 1$

and

$\sum_0^\infty \theta^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - \theta}, \tag 2$

so

$\sum_1^\infty \theta^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - \theta} - 1 = (1 - \theta)^{-1} - 1, \tag 3$

whence

$\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\sum_1^\infty \theta^n = \dfrac{d}{d\theta}( (1 - \theta)^{-1} - 1) = (1 - \theta)^{-2}, \tag 4$

thus

$\sum_1^\infty n \theta^n = \dfrac{\theta}{(1 - \theta)^2}, \tag 5$

a closed-form expression.

We can in fact see how the factors $n$ arise if we look at the square of $(1 - \theta)^{-1}$:

$(1 - \theta)^{-2} = ((1 - \theta)^{-1})^2 = (\sum_0^\infty \theta^n)^2 = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{i = 0}^n \theta^i \theta^{n -i} = \sum_0^\infty (n + 1) \theta^n, \tag 6$

whence

$\dfrac{\theta}{(1 - \theta)^2} = \theta \sum_0^\infty (n + 1) \theta^n =  \sum_0^\infty (n + 1) \theta^{n + 1} = \sum_1^\infty n\theta^n; \tag 7$

(6)-(7) seems to be another derivation of the desired result.