# Convergent value of $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sum in question is:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}$$

It passes the ratio test:

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}}{n\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}}\\
=\frac{5}{6}&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)}{n}\frac{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}}{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}}\\
=\frac{5}{6}&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+ \frac{1}{n})\\
=\frac{5}{6} &< 1\Rightarrow \text{convergent}
\end{align}
But now I do not know how to find the convergent value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112394/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-nxn-1)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  The other question asks how to evaluate the sum without relying on the derivative of the closed form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\\
f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
f'(5/6)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac{5}{6})^{n-1}= 36.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hmm so write $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$. We know how to write this as a geometric series sum, and know the answer is $\frac{x}{1-x}$ (whenever $|x|<1$, which is the case with $x=5/6$ fortunately.

Now we will differentiate $f(x)$ and set $x=5/6$. We are allowed to do this by Taylor's theorem and term by term differentiation, because our series is just a Taylor series for $f(x)$.

If we differentiate the expression $\frac{x}{1-x}$ in $x$ and set $x=5/6$ we will get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the geometric sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Take the derivative of both sides:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Your sum appears when $x=5/6$. The above sums only hold if $|x|<1$ which does hold here.

Comment: Your answer was just as good as Robert Shore's but I marked his as correct, thus is life.