# How to compute $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xa^x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Need a hint to compute $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^\infty xa^x$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2a^x$, where $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: This will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647587/sum-of-a-power-series-n-xn

Comment: Why that strange way to write the limits in the sum?

Comment: I've posted answers to this question several times.  I wonder if it's our most frequently re-posted question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: He seems to be the first to also ask about $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty n^2 a^n$.

Comment: @Brenton: Apparently, the original is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/sequence-sum-question

Comment: @AlexM. : I'm pretty sure I've posted answers to that one too.  If you throw a die repeatedly until you get the first $1$, what is the variance of the random variable that is the number of times you throw it?  The answer to that question involves the series you say no one has asked about. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 a^n = \left(a^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)a^{n-2}\right) + \left(a\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a^{n-1}\right)={}$ $a^2$ times the second derivative of a function defined by a geometric series, plus $a$ times the first derivative. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Differentiate $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}a^x$ with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the genral term and rewrite as
$$ia^i=a(ia^{i-1})=a\frac{d}{da}(a^i)$$
So we can write the series as
$$a\frac{d}{da}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a^i=a\frac{d}{da}\frac{1}{1-a}=\frac{a^2}{(1-a)^2}$$
I leave the second one to you. Hope this helps.