# An inequality about prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $t\geq 1$ be an integer number, and $p$ a prime number. What fraction can we set on the right side to have a correct inequality?
$$\sum_{t\geq 1}\frac{t}{p^{t}-1}< \ldots$$
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I don't know where to start?

Comment: I don't think this is true - should the inequality be the other way round?

Comment: You might start by evaluating the two sides numerically for some small primes $p$.

Comment: For $p$ a prime, $p>2$, we have $\frac{1}{p-1} > \frac{p}{(p-1)^3}$ and if you take the first couple of terms of the series, you will also find it is false for $p=2$.

Comment: The $t=1$ term on the left is already greater than the right side if $p \ge 3$.

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $t\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\frac{t}{p^t-1} \leqslant \frac{t}{p^{t-1}}$ since $p^t$ and $p^{t-1}$ differ by at least $1$. If you're trying to show the series converges, you can find many questions on the site about how to sum the series $\sum\frac{n}{p^n}$ .

Comment: @ A. Goodier, Thank you very much. I want to replace a fraction (according to $p$) on the right side to have an true inequality.

Comment: Yes, so if you sum the series $\sum\frac{t}{p^{t-1}}$, you will get $\frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the answer I gave in the comments:

If $p$ is prime and $t\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $p^{t-1}\leqslant p^t-1$, so $\dfrac{1}{p^t-1}\leqslant \dfrac{1}{p^{t-1}}$ .

Hence
$$\sum_{t\ge1}\frac{t}{p^t-1}\le\sum_{t\ge1}\frac{t}{p^{t-1}}=\sum_{t\ge0}\frac{t+1}{p^t}=\sum_{t\ge0}\frac{t}{p^t}+\sum_{t\ge0}\frac{1}{p^t}=\frac{p}{(p-1)^2}+\frac{p}{p-1}=\frac{p^2}{(p-1)^2}\,.$$
To evaluate the last two series, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/sequence-sum-question-sum-n-0-inftynkn?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the first series and use the geometric series formula for the second series.

Comment: @ A. Goodier, Thanks a lot. I saw the previous (incorrect) inequality in a paper published in a math journal!!! Thank you for your help to correct it. Is it possible to replace $\frac{p}{(p-1)^{2}}$ instead of $\frac{p^{2}}{(p-1)^{2}}$ in your answer?

Comment: @Mary No, with $\frac{p}{(p-1)^2}$ the inequality does not hold.

Comment: @ A. Goodier, unfortunately, in that paper it is assumed the inequality $\sum_{t\geq 1}\frac{t}{p^{t}-1}<\frac{p}{(p-1)^{2}}$ is true!

Comment: @Mary it must be wrong - you can check numerically that this is false for various values of $p$

Comment: @ A. Goodier, Thanks again for your time and your complete answers.